# Multiple inheritance with templated template

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, c++20

I want to do multiple inheritance via template arguments and pass reference to `this` in each base class, so I can call top level object's method from each base class's method. I can do it with manual inheritance, but I want to be able to do this via templates arguments.

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/f4Wzs1EfT)

[Godbolt link with manual inheritance](https://godbolt.org/z/PGzde4rdd)

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(T &t)
        : t_(t) {

    }

    void foo() {
        t_.call("foo");
    }

    T &t_;
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar {
    Bar(T &t)
        : t_(t) {

    }

    void bar() {
        t_.call("bar");
    }

    T &t_;
};

template <template<typename> typename... Methods>
struct Impl : public Methods<Impl>... {
    Impl() 
        : Methods<Impl>(*this)... {

    }

    void call(const char *m) {
        printf(m);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto t = Impl<Foo, Bar>();

    t.foo();
    t.bar();
}
```

I tried this approach, but it gives
`type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class> class ... Methods'`

Comment: So... what's the question? You seem to have some code. Is that code non-functional in some way? If so, what errors are you getting? Also, you don't really need to pass a base class a `this` pointer; they already have one, and if they know that they are a base class of `T`, then they can `static_cast<T*>(this)` to get a pointer to the derived class. This is part of the CRTP and is a semi-common C++ tool.

Comment: But how I can cast them to base class if top level class is template? and individual base class doesn't know whole template list for top level one. Question is - how to achieve this? I got compilation errors, will edit question

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo Please put all relevant information in the question. Links tend to get stale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Nicol Bolas, he advised to use `static_cast` and CRTP for this

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    void foo() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->call("foo");
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar {
    void bar() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->call("bar");
    }
};

template <template<typename> typename... Methods>
struct Impl : public Methods<Impl<Methods...>>... {
    Impl() {

    }

    void call(const char *m) {
        printf(m);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto t = Impl<Foo, Bar>();

    t.foo();
    t.bar();
}
```